# Pyspark - most efficient way to combine `agg` count and a filtered count

Tags: python, performance, pyspark, aggregate

If you have a pyspark dataframe `df`, what is the most efficient way to get a total count of rows and a filtered count of rows? In this particular example, I'm counting the total number of rows and the total number of rows where `column` includes a comma.

```
df.agg(count('*').alias('Records'),
       sum(expr("case when column like '%,%' then 1 else 0 end")).alias('Counts with comma'))
```

Another option would be `count(when(expr(...)))`:

```
df.agg(count('*').alias('Records'),
         count(when(expr("column like '%,%'"), col('column'))).alias('Counts with comma')).show()
```

In terms of these two options, their `.explain` output is virtually the same except of course for the different functions.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?